# Different item size in a grouped gridView

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I created a Grouped GridView with an item template and header template. It works well but then I would like the first article of my list to have a different template (to be bigger). Like the french application "LeMonde" for example. I have no idea of how I could define the template to achieve that.

Here is my current xaml code

```
<Page.Resources>
 <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs1" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">

    <GridView  x:Name="PicturesGridView" SelectionMode="None"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs1}}"IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="RectanglesStackPanel" Margin="8" Orientation="Vertical" Width="242">

                    <Image Source="{Binding imageUrl}" Height="180"  Width="225"   Stretch="UniformToFill" />

                    <Border Background="Gray" Opacity="1" Width="225" Height="115">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"
           Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="215" FontSize="18" />
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <Button  Click="Button_Click_1" Content="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" FontSize="30" Margin="0,0,0,-10" ></Button>     
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>


</Grid>
```

I just bind my list of item in C# like this :

```
this.cvs1.Source = ListOfArticle;
```

Thank you in advance :)

---

Thank you Ivan. It helps me a lot. However the code provided in the example doesn't seem up to date for Windows 8. Do you have any ideas of how we can access a template defined in the ressources of a page. The FindRessources Method doesn't exist anymore. I tried with this code instead but it wasn't successful :

```
 public class AuctionItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
 {
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, 
                                                  DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Article)
        {
            Article auctionItem = item as Article;

            DataTemplate mySmallTemplate = element.FindName("SmallTemplate") as DataTemplate;

            switch (auctionItem.isFirstItem)
            {
                case true:
                    return
                  element.FindName("BigTemplate") as DataTemplate;

                case false:
                    return
                   element.FindName("SmallTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

'

Comment: You shouldn't put things like "windows 8" in your title.  That's what tags are for.

Comment: Yes: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I followed the way of creating a custom DataTemplateSelector with all needed templates as properties.

```
namespace Helper
{
    public class CustomSampleDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate FirstDataTemplate { get; set; }

        public DataTemplate SecondDataTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, 
                  DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is FirstItemType)
                return FirstDataTemplate ;
            if (item is SecondItemType)
                return SecondDataTemplate;
            else
                return FirstDataTemplate ;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it directly in XAML like this:

Declare resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate1">
        <Border Background="White">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontSize="40"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate2">
        <Border Background="Orange">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShopName}"
                           FontSize="64"
                           Foreground="LightBlue"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Common:CustomSampleDataTemplateSelector x:Key="mySelector"
                                     FirstDataTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate1}"
                                     SecondDataTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate2}">
    </Common:CustomSampleDataTemplateSelector >
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Use it

```
<GridView  x:Name="PicturesGridView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mySelector}">
```

That's all

Answer (score 4):

Thank you. It actually works well because it makes the first item having a different template than the other. However it was not what I wanted sorry it's my fault I wasn't clear.
 Because with your technique the item size in the grid view has always the same size. 
Let's say I choose myTemplate1 to have a grid with a width of 400 and myTemplate2 a grid with a width of 200. Then if my first element follows myTemplate1, all the element of the grid view will have a size of 400 even if the image inside is only 200.

I wanted to achieve a result like in this article : http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/03/07/Databinding-to-the-VariableSizedWrapGrid-in-Windows-8-Metro.aspx

So I found what I actually needed it's VariableSizedWrapGrid and to reimplement a version of a gridView.I Followed this very good article : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423.

However I'll mark your answer as correct because it answer my initial question : it allows to select different item size in a group grid view.

Thank you very much for your time it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single ItemTemplate for all items in the GridView you have to define different ItemTemplate for 1st element and then for all the others.

In order to do that you have to remote ItemTemplate defined and use ItemTemplateSelector to determine which style to use.

Here you can find more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx